# Deploy de um app ruby no Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

Estou tentando fazer o deploy de um app em ruby no Heroku.
A log toda está **[neste link](https://pastebin.com/Cvspep4X)**.

Eu achava que era o erro abaixo (que aparece em parte da log), mas mesmo depois de instalar o Yarn (incluí no gem e dei um bundle install), continuo tendo problemas.

```
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução do seu problema está em https://blog.heroku.com/yarn-deterministic-dependency-resolution